# Google Photos sync to Windows

Tags: sync, photos, google-photos

Ok, this is a long shot but let's see if is anyone have an answer.

I'm using Google Photos and the Windows desktop app "Backup and Sync". When I upload a picture on my computer (e.g. from my camera) it syncs to Google Photos. My mobile phone (Android) also uploads to Google Photos - great. I have configured Google Drive to "Automatically put your Google Photos in a folder in My Drive". That way all the pictures get synced back to my PC, both from mobile and from my camera. The camera pictures actually don't become duplicated since I use the same folder for upload/download.

The problem occurs when using Shared Libraries. My wife has a shared album. When she snaps a photo it is automatically shared. I have configured to automatically download all photos that are shared. So they end up in my Google Photos. This is awesome since I have all my photos backed up in a single library: my camera, my phone, my wifes phone.

The problem is that the Drive setting "Automatically put your Google Photos in a folder in My Drive" isn't working for the photos saved from the shared library. So I get 2/3 pictures to my Drive. The Drive folder syncs to my computer. So when I open Lightroom to build a photo album from the synced Drive folder I only have my own photos, not the photos from my wifes phone.

So the question is: does anyone know how to automatically save pictures from a shared library and have these uploaded to my Drive? Alternative would be to sync the Google Photos library to my computer but I can't find an app to do that besides using the "put in my Drive" setting.

EDIT:
Hmm. By re-toggling the Google Drive setting "Automatically put your Google Photos in a folder in My Drive" it syncs the shared pictures as well. Unfortunately it loses/rewrites capture time so the sort order is now broken in Google Drive.

I wish I could just one-way sync my Google Photos to my computer but Google removed that app in favour of the current non-working Backup & Sync app *sigh*